# Open/Close Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services

I have a Service.  We are sending records to this service.  However, when we send too many records (3,000) the Service times out.  My idea was to break up the records and open the Service, then close it every 1,000 records.

However, I am getting an error:

```
{"Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel'."}
```

Here is my code:

```
ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
foreach (Record rc in creditTransactionList)
{
    //if we are not on the last one...
    if (currentTransCount < totalTransCount)
    {
        //Current batch count is less than 1,000
        if (currentBatchCount <= amountPerBatch)
        {
            currentBatchCount++;
            if (rc != null)
                client.RecordInsert(rc);
        }
        //Current batch count is 1,000
        if (currentBatchCount == amountPerBatch)
        {
            currentBatchCount = 0;
            client.Close();
            client.Open();
        }
        //Increment Total Counter by 1
        currentTransCount++;
    }
    else
    {
        currentBatchCount++;
        if (rc != null)
            client.RecordInsert(rc);
        client.Close();
    }
}

amountPerBatch = 1000;
totalTransCount = ACHTransactionList.Count();
currentBatchCount = 0;
currentTransCount = 1;

foreach (Record rc in ACHTransactionList)
{
    //if we are not on the last one...
    if (currentTransCount < totalTransCount)
    {
        //Current batch count is less than 1,000
        if (currentBatchCount <= amountPerBatch)
        {
            currentBatchCount++;
            if (rc != null)
                client.RecordInsert(rc);
        }
        //Current batch count is 1,000
        if (currentBatchCount == amountPerBatch)
        {
            currentBatchCount = 0;
            client.Close();
            client.Open();
        }
        //Increment Total Counter by 1
        currentTransCount++;
    }
    else
    {
        currentBatchCount++;
        if (rc != null)
            client.RecordInsert(rc);
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

I created a sample console application that does this, but when i actually incorporated it into the actual project with the actual service, I get an error.  Can you please help me figure out what I am doing wrong.  It has to be my client.open and client.close, is my guess.  Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I suspect your service client is a bit of a one shot thing, try creating a new one for each batch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would try something more like this...
Note that you should always `.Dispose()` the client as well. Also, if an error occurs, then `.Close()` no longer works on the client, instead you have to `.Abort()` it.

```
ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
try
{
  foreach(...)
  {
    ...
    //Current batch count is 1,000
    if (currentBatchCount == amountPerBatch)
    {
        currentBatchCount = 0;
        client.Close();
        client = new ServiceClient();
    }
    ...
  }
}
finally
{
  if(client.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
    client.Abort();
  else
    client.Close();
}
```

Comment: Just a friendly FYI - you cannot call client.Dispose(), that is not valid syntax because that method is not available to be called.

Comment: @dyslexicanaboko - that is incorrect. WCF clients are of type `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<>` which implement `IDisposable` and therefore has a `.Dispose()` method. Here is the MSDN page for the method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340248(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No offense, but go write that code and try to compile it, you will get a syntax error. That's the only reason I am saying it.

Comment: @dyslexicanaboko - ah, it seems that currently `ClientBase` implements `Dispose` explicitly, so you are correct, it can not be called as in my code. My code sample was based on something I had in production at the time so I'm pretty sure it used to be callable. Maybe Microsoft changed `ClientBase` over the last 3 years since this answer was created? If I remember correctly this was written for .NET 3.5.

Comment: Oh yeah man, they changed it a heck of a lot. I had a fun time trying to figure out why my production code broke magically without any releases after infrastructure upgraded the .Net framework from 4 to 4.5 - MS shifted a bunch of namespaces from one assembly to another which made you have to updated your references whether you planned on it or not. Just an example of some stuff that changed, but yes it has changed plenty :D

Comment: Hi, from 2017. Is this still the best way to do this, or some new built in function has been implemented by Ms?.

Answer (score 1):

`client.Close` will dispose the object. `client.Open` will always throw error after that.
You need to initialize client with `new ServiceClient();`

Comment: I tried to initialize client by doing `ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();` again, however I get an error of: `A local variable named 'client' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'client', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else`

Answer (score 0):

What I do is check the state of the client and reset it if necessary:

```
if (wsClient.State.Equals(CommunicationState.Faulted) || wsClient.State.Equals(CommunicationState.Closed) || wsClient.State.Equals(CommunicationState.Closing))
                {
                    wsClient = new ServiceClient();
                }
```